# Angular Components are not Aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In my app, I have a tab. Inside this tab, there is a dropdown list and a button. I want to align these two components while aligning the dropdown to start and the button to end. I have tried the approach in my code yet, they are still not aligned as you can see. Also, I can not stretch the dropdown horizontally, it stays like the image below. What should I do to achieve what I want?

[image]

Code:

```
<div fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between end" fxLayout="column" class="m-8 mb-16">
    <div fxLayout="column" class="mt-16 mr-8" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="100" class="pr-4">
            <mat-label>Şube Kodu Seçimi</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="this._materialPlan.StockBranch" name="StockBranch">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let dp of branchList" [value]="dp">
                    {{dp.BranchName}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" class="mt-16 mr-8" fxLayoutAlign="end center" style="margin-top: 200px;">
            <button mat-stroked-button [ngClass]="{'purple-fg': EditIndex==undefined}" [disabled]="EditIndex!=undefined"
            (click)="openProductSelectionDialog(); workItemForm.reset();">
            Yeni Ürün
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.m-8 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I recommend adding proper classnames though instead of using m-8 which is probably a framework class?